# React-Native-Elements: Showing image component in the center of the rounded Avatar

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

I am using [react-native-elements](https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/avatar.html) to render an `Avatar` , I have a image to be shown in a rounded circle Avatar & I would like the image to be in the center of the circle Avatar.

This is what I tried:

```
<Avatar
   size={60}
   containerStyle={{backgroundColor: 'black'}}
   rounded
   ImageComponent={MyImg}
   avatarStyle={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}
 />
```

`MyImg` is a tsx file that is converted from a SVG.

The above code results to `MyImg` showing on the top left position of the rounded Avatar.

Then I tried:

```
<Avatar
       size={60}
       containerStyle={{backgroundColor: 'black', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}
       rounded
       ImageComponent={MyImg}
       avatarStyle={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}
     />
```

This code makes `MyImg` disappear. So, I get stuck now.

How to make the image component showing in the center ?

**==== more info ====**

Here is `MyImg.tsx` file:

```
function SvgMyImg(props) {
  return (
    <Svg width={24} height={24} fill="none" {...props}>
      <Path
        d="M7 7l10 10M17 7L7 17"
        stroke="#fff"
        strokeWidth={2}
        strokeLinecap="round"
      />
    </Svg>
  );
}

export default SvgMyImg;
```

I just import this file e.g. `import MyImg from '../assets/images/MyImg';` and use it as the `imageComponent` of `Avatar` like my code shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried something like what you want to do in [snack.expo](https://snack.expo.io/qcNatmMn2). The key is using `position:absolute`

```js
 <View style={styles.container}>
      <Avatar
        size={60}
        containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'black' }}
        rounded
        ImageComponent={() => (
          <Image
            resizeMode="contain"
            style={{
              height: 30,
              width: 30,
              borderRadius: 25,
              position: 'absolute',
            }}
            source={{
              uri: 'https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/boat.png',
            }}
          />
        )}
        overlayContainerStyle={{
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}
      />
    </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Avatar
   size={60}
   containerStyle={{backgroundColor: 'black', width: 70, height: 70, padding: 5}}
   rounded
   ImageComponent={MyImg}
 />
```

Comment: No, I tried it as well, it doesn't work. My image just disappear with this code.

Comment: Why not just using the svg file with react-native-svg-loader ?

Comment: That could be an option, but outside the scope of my question, anyhow I would like to know how to make it work with my current approach.  Changing everything back to SVG is a big thing in my project I wouldn't consider now unless it is the only option to make it work.

Comment: You can try to set the avatar size to 60, but container to 70, for example, with a padding of 5

Comment: It stretches circle, which is not I want. But now I updated my question with the code of `MyImg` file.

Comment: Check at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49942872/how-to-center-an-svg-in-react-native

Comment: Thanks, but the issue there is to display a image & solution is to wrap it in a View component, my issue is showing the image inside an Avatar, which is different. I don't see it helps my issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Avatar
   size={60}
   containerStyle={{flex:1, backgroundColor: 'black', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}
   rounded
   ImageComponent={MyImg}
/>
```

Try this

It would be great if you provide `Img` Component in short

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't help either. But I now provided the tsx file of `MyImg` in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have added margins to the avatar. It worked for me.

```
        <Avatar
          size={120}
          containerStyle={{
            backgroundColor: '#F6F6F6',
          }}
          rounded
          ImageComponent={MyImg}
          avatarStyle={{
            marginLeft: 38,
            marginTop: 20,
          }}>
```